# Multiple Light Sources with GL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to do something basic with GL. However I got a problem with the lights. I have a cube in the viewport and when I put GL_LIGHT0 at some point, it shades the cube without any problem. But GL_LIGHT1 does not act normally. When I disable light0 and put GL_LIGHT1 at the same location of light0, it just gives a different color to the shape. No shading, no lighting.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default values for `GL_AMBIENT`, `GL_DIFFUSE`, `GL_SPECULAR` with `GL_LIGHT0` is (1,1,1), while it is (0,0,0) for `GL_LIGHT1` to `GL_LIGHT6`.

If you set these values using `glLight*`, you should see consistent behaviour.